# Total reputation, average reputation, or rolling reputation: leveling the playing field?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

In one of the stackoverflow podcasts, Jeff pondered the idea of having a reputation limit.  The concern was that certain users (e.g. Jon Skeet) will get so far ahead and might discourage other users.  I don't particularly see that as a *huge* problem because most people aren't doing this in order to become the #1 user on the site.  On the other hand, promoting competition for good questions and answers is certainly a goal of the site, and being an early user of the site leads to a higher reputation and doesn't evenly promote the competitive spirit.

One way to address this would be to have two stats next to everyone's name: their **total reputation** and their "**average reputation**" (total reputation divided by the number of days that they've been using the site).  Alternatively, you could put a "**rolling reputation**" (the reputation over the past year, for instance).  In essence, you could base it on a sports metaphor: this a new reputation *season*.

What do people think?  Would that be worthwhile?  Of course, I would still expect the top users to lead in this category (over 200 a day), but it would also motivate late adopters.

Comment: @ChrisF that would still be a rolling reputation.

Comment: @Rene - my (now deleted) comment was added before the post was edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've previously suggested a "monthly league" for reputation, which was a popular idea... although as you say, the usual suspects would probably be near the top.

One interesting point would be to have *two* reputation graphs (either show one at a time, or overlay them) - one would be absolute reputation, and the other would be reputation gained per day, basically the gradient of the first. I'd be interested in seeing that, certainly - and it can easily be done with the existing data. (Heck, it could be done with the data which is already being shipped down to the browser - it could be entirely client-side.)

Showing the average per-day rep in things like the Users screen would be interesting as well, certainly.

One problem with this: it all focuses people a little too heavily on reputation. Reputation should be a corollary of giving good answers, rather than the driving force. That doesn't mean I'm not hopeful of *one day* achieving 500 in a day without bounty of course...

Answer (score 4):

Reputation leagues are now rolled out:
https://stackexchange.com/leagues

Blog entry:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/network-central-stackexchange-com/

Answer (score 3):

Please, don't.

I put time into SO when I can.  That isn't very much time, so my rep growth over time is slow.  If I put a lot of time into it in a day, I can make some strides, but I have more important tasks.  I think I may have a rep/day of <15.

Further, those who have been members a long time are then at a disadvantage, particularly if they have to neglect SO for a while to address real-life issues... their rep will be averaged over a longer time period that doesn't reflect their trustworthiness.

I think the amount of rep you can get from asking lots of stupid, badly worded questions is a much larger issue, as is the rep from the 'fun' questions.  Worry about how rep is gained, not how much Jon Skeet, et. al. have.

Comment: I'm not suggesting replacing the existing system, just adding to it.  Are you saying that you would be at a disadvantage because you've been a member for a long time but don't contribute much?  Isn't that the whole point?

Comment: Yeah, that's the whole point.  The point that I _don't like_.  It isn't 'leveling the playing field' at all.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea, but I think that it might be a bit more interesting if the linked account box was updated to have the total reputation as well as the average number of up-votes per answer. This might need to be tweaked a bit to exclude outlier questions due to popularity, but might give a fair idea of how their responses are accepted by the community.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the best idea would be to focus on average reputation *per post*. That way people are rewarded for quality rather than quantity.

Comment: And for sticking to the top-viewed tags...

Comment: true, but isn't that also true if the focus is on absolute reputation?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't particularly see that as a big problem because most people aren't doing this in order to become the #1 user on the site
>
> (...) being an early user of the site does lead to a higher reputation and might be considered an unfair advantage

Isn't that a little contradictory?

Comment: @Juan:  Not really.  The first sentence gives his personal opinion, the second sentence gives a hypothetical third parties' opinion (note the use of the passive voice).

Comment: So, he doesn't think this is a problem, but he wonders if others might, and if so, how it could be addressed.

Comment: @Adam, oh... ok

Comment: Fair point.  I clarified further.